# Strange ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error for Rails 3.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails. I was working on a new rails project which is a Library System and while trying to access Loan_fines
I am getting an strange error.

The error is as follows:-

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in LoanFinesController#index

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "loan_fines" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

My LoanFines controller is as follows:-

```
class LoanFinesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /loan_fines
  # GET /loan_fines.json
  def index
    @loan_fines = LoanFine.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @loan_fines }
    end
  end

  # GET /loan_fines/1
  # GET /loan_fines/1.json
  def show
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @loan_fine }
    end
  end

  # GET /loan_fines/new
  # GET /loan_fines/new.json
  def new
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @loan_fine }
    end
  end

  # GET /loan_fines/1/edit
  def edit
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /loan_fines
  # POST /loan_fines.json
  def create
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.new(params[:loan_fine])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @loan_fine.save
        format.html { redirect_to @loan_fine, notice: 'Loan fine was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @loan_fine, status: :created, location: @loan_fine }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @loan_fine.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /loan_fines/1
  # PUT /loan_fines/1.json
  def update
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @loan_fine.update_attributes(params[:loan_fine])
        format.html { redirect_to @loan_fine, notice: 'Loan fine was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @loan_fine.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /loan_fines/1
  # DELETE /loan_fines/1.json
 def delete
    @loan_fine = LoanFine.find(params[:id])
    @loan_fine.deleted = 1
    @loan_fine.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to loan_fines_url }
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
    end
  end 
end
```

My index for Loan Fines id as follows:-

```
<h1 class="List">Listing Loan Fines</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered" >
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Category Id</th>
    <th>Loan Duration</th>
    <th>Book Id</th>
    <th>Fine Amount</th>
    <th>Fine Duration</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

<% @loan_fines.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to c.id, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.category_id %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.loan_duration %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.book_id %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.fine_amount %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.fine_duration %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this value?" } %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New Loan fine', new_loan_fine_path %>
```

My log has the following:-

```
Started GET "/loan_fines" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-29 22:36:37 -0700
Processing by LoanFinesController#index as HTML
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "loan_fines" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "loan_fines" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"loan_fines"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  app/controllers/loan_fines_controller.rb:5:in `index'


  Rendered /home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered /home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.3ms)
```

I am getting stuck at this.The strangest part of this is that the same code seems to `work on windows` but while trying on `Ubuntu am getting an error`.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: You should add your models too...

Comment: You have a `LoanFine` model but not `load_fines` table in your PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @muistooshort I have the table in the database

Comment: You wouldn't be getting a `relation "loan_fines" does not exist` error if you did. Access your database with `psql`, say `select '"load_fines"'::regclass` or `select * from load_fines` and you'll get the same sort of error.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work @Catmandu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like db error. Run `rake db:migrate` and `rake test:prepare` at first.

Comment: I did rake db:migrate.It is showing Db already exists.What do I do now

Comment: It must be db error. If rake taks can't help, you need to check your db setting and db connection manually to see if they are correct.